# React project has Firebase Emulator ApiKey Error

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-tools

i have recently connected my React project to Firebase emulator. On the production environment, the app worked as it should but since moving to emulator, its unpredictable.

I get the following errors when I start the local emulator:

```
POST https://firebaseinstallations.googleapis.com/v1/projects/demo-project/installations 400
```

and

```
FirebaseError: Installations: Create Installation request failed with error "400 INVALID_ARGUMENT: API key not valid. Please pass a valid API key." (installations/request-failed).
```

Here is my code in my firebase.js file:

```
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: process.env.REACT_APP_APIKEY,
  authDomain: process.env.REACT_APP_AUTHDOMAIN,
  projectId: process.env.REACT_APP_PROJECTID,
  storageBucket: process.env.REACT_APP_STORAGEBUCKET,
  messagingSenderId: process.env.REACT_APP_MESSAGINGSENDERID,
  appId: process.env.REACT_APP_APPID,
  measurementId: process.env.REACT_APP_MEASUREMENTID,
};

const hostname = window.location.hostname;
const app =
  hostname === "localhost"
    ? initializeApp({
        apiKey: "demo-key",
        authDomain: "demo-test",
        projectId: "demo-project",
        storageBucket: "default-bucket",
        appId: "demo-appId",
      })
    : initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

export let auth = getAuth(app);
export let db = getFirestore(app);
export const storage = getStorage(app);
export let functions = getFunctions(app);
export const analytics = getAnalytics(app);

if (hostname === "localhost") {
  connectAuthEmulator(auth, "http://localhost:9099");
  connectFirestoreEmulator(db, "localhost", 8080);
  connectStorageEmulator(storage, "localhost", 9199);
  connectFunctionsEmulator(functions, "localhost", 5001);
}
```

I have tried several configurations to resolve this error to no avail and without an apiKey, key/value pair, the local site doesn't render.

Any insights would be appreciated.

Comment: Does the code above get executed before the error or is the error on emulator startup

Comment: @Chris, the error is on the the localhost startup when the emulator is on.

Comment: Agree with @Chris. It looks like your React app for some reason calls production backend and databases. Emulator is not strict on the keys. Cannot reproduce it locally, the app starts as expected without key errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAICT "API key not valid" isn't thrown by the emulator, which leads me to believe you're calling production.

A few things to check:

- Ensure you're starting the emulators with `demo-project` like so:

`firebase emulators:start --project=demo-project`

- Make sure your browser's URL is actually "localhost" and not an explicit IP address, since `window.location.hostname` returns the host based on the browser URL
- See if the `getAnalytics` call is causing the problem - there's no emulated Analytics service so this may be calling prod with "demo-project" and will necessarily fail.

Comment: I am using ```firebase emulators:start --project=demo-project``` and the browser url is ```http://localhost:3000/```

Comment: See my latest edit - try removing `getAnalytics` and see if that resolves the issue you're seeing.